# Making a cron-scheduled database backup (dump) without exposing the password in /etc/crontab

Tags: cron, password, mysql, database

I use the following `/etc/crontab` code to create daily backups of my database in limit of the last 30 days:

```
0 8 * * * mysqldump -u root -PASSWORD --all-databases > /root/backups/mysql/db.sql
1 8 * * * zip /root/backups/mysql/db-$(date +\%F-\%T-).sql.zip /root/backups/mysql/db.sql
2 8 * * * rm /root/backups/mysql/db.sql
2 8 * * * find /root/backups/mysql/* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

### My problem:

I must put my password where `-PASSWORD`. This way my password is exposed if by mistake I entered to change something in this file and someone near to me saw it.

Is it possible to use the script without putting the password there? Alternatively, do you know a similar syntax that won't force me to write the password there for a cronjob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a script to do the complete dump, backup and cleanup.
2. Schedule the script.

Additionally, the password to `mysql` may also be stored in a protected file and does not need to be given on the command line.

MySQL has a "[End-User Guidelines for Password Security](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html)" document that you may want to consult.

To summarize that document:

Create `.my.cnf` in your home directory and add the password to it like this:

```
[client]
password=your_pass
```

Then remove read-permissions on the file for other users:

```
$ chmod 600 .my.cnf
```

or, equivalently,

```
$ chmod u=rw,go-rwx .my.cnf
```

This file, if named `.my.cnf` and placed in you home directory, will automatically be used by the `mysql` client program (as well as by `mysqldump`).

Still, do put the backup etc. into its own script and schedule that instead. That will be a whole lot easier to maintain than a number of cron jobs.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I'll most likely move this to a script, but is there no way not use a password at all? I mean, I am the only one who uses this server and there is no sign it's going to change... Creating a protected file and reference it each time a password is needed seems to a non minimalist solution I would want to avoid, for now.

Comment: @Benia If you use the name `~/.my.cnf` for the configuration file, it will _automatically_ be used by the MySQL client.

Comment: @Benia Also, you can not seriously be concerned about putting your password in the crontab, and then say that you'd rather have _no_ password.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I malexplained myself. I meant that I would rather not use a password for creating dumps, because I personally see no security threat in exporting dumps. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Benia The `musqldump` process attaches to the database as a client, just like the `mysql` client or any other process does that needs to query it. To be able to do that, it needs to authenticate with the server. You could possibly create a user on the server that only has the permissions needed to perform a dump, but that would mean that anyone could connect as that user and do a dump, not just your cronjob.

Comment: Oh, yes, I meant --- I don't see a threat when I do so, but of course, what your wrote relates to that as well... Hmm, I might just go on the first solution you suggest.

Comment: I do wonder why, when it is done from root (/etc/crontab) I still need to use the password. I think an execption for root (to be distinguished from `sudo` or `su`) should be a special case... But, it's just my thought I felt a need to present.

Comment: @Benia The database server has a totally separate set of users from the what's on the system. This means that even root has to go through authentication to get to the data through a client.